# Lost frames on synchrous/asynchrous data receiveing

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have some problem with receiving frames in C#. After few hours from application start, some frames are lost.

Well, at start I'm running two threads which are receiving data. Code:

```
    public void ATSListenerThreadA(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        UdpClient listenerA = new UdpClient(19001);

        listenerA.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 1000;

        IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPointA = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1);

        Byte[] receivedBytes;

        try
        {
            while (mainWindow.ATSThreadActive)
            {
                receivedBytes = listenerA.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPointA);

                if (receivedBytes.Length > 170)
                {
                    Log.Write(MessageType.Info, "BUG KANAL A: " + BitConverter.ToString(receivedBytes));
                }

                mainWindow.ATSTimeoutTimer.Start();

                ATSDataReceived(Channel.A, mainWindow, receivedBytes);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void ATSListenerThreadB(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        UdpClient listenerB = new UdpClient(19002);

        listenerB.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 1000;

        IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPointB = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1);

        Byte[] receivedBytes;

        try
        {
            while (mainWindow.ATSThreadActive)
            {
                receivedBytes = listenerB.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPointB);

                if (receivedBytes.Length > 170)
                {
                    Log.Write(MessageType.Info, "BUG KANAL B: " + BitConverter.ToString(receivedBytes));
                }

                mainWindow.ATSTimeoutTimer.Start();

                ATSDataReceived(Channel.B, mainWindow, receivedBytes);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ATSDataReceived(Channel channel, MainWindow mainWindow, Byte[] received)
    {
        try
        {
            mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                mainWindow.ATSStatusLabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
                mainWindow.ATSStatusLabel.Content = "OK";
            });

            ATSInterface.UpdateObjects(channel, received);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                mainWindow.ATSStatusLabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
                mainWindow.ATSStatusLabel.Content = "ERR";
            });

            Log.Write(MessageType.Warning, ex.Message);
        }

        lock (this)
        {
            if (mainWindow.ATSTimeoutTimer != null)
            {
                mainWindow.ATSTimeoutTimer.Stop();
                mainWindow.ATSTimeoutTimer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, in ATSDataReceived method, received data are processed with calling method ATSInterface.UpdateObjects(). Of course inside ATSInterface.UpdateObjects() method is lock. I was trying to receiving data synchronously and asynchronously, but it doesn't change anything. Also I was checking if two frames are not sticking together, but it's not this too. As I said, problem araises after few hours from program start, in both threads simultaneously.

I might add that frames are coming very often, once at ~150 ms.

What can be a reason?

Answer (score 2):

> some frames are lost.

That's perfectly normal for UDP. By design, you may or may not ever receive a datagram that was sent to you.

Other unreliable behaviors of UDP include the possibility that a given datagram may be received more than once, and that one datagram may be received after a different datagram that was sent later than it (i.e. the datagrams are not guaranteed to be received in the same order in which they were sent).

If you want reliable communications, you will need to use TCP, or add reliability features on top of your UDP protocol.

Comment: @user3209687: `localhost` has a lot fewer reasons to toss out UDP datagrams. For that matter, UDP could work fine for weeks on end on the Internet without any reliability problems. It's not that UDP is guaranteed _to fail_. It's just that it's _not guaranteed_ to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

udp is unreliable protocol to use.

if you want to make sure that everything arrives you need to use TcpClient instead.